# Nodemailer DNS config doesn't seem to be working

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

Need help with setting DNS information on my nodemailer email message config on my nodeJS project
I tried setting a DSN Recipient gets ignored and the dsn is never sent.

Sample Code:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1025,
    secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
});
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'anaddress@a.domain.net',
    to: 'anaddress@a.domain.net',
    subject: 'Test Receipt',
    text: 'Did you get a failure?',
    envelope: {
    dsn: {
        id: 'messageId',
        return: 'FULL',
        notify: 'success',
        recipient: 'anotheraddress@a.domain.net',
    },
    },
}, (err, info) => {
    console.log(info.envelope);
    console.log(info.messageId);
});
```